# Concatenate multiple arrays on excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

A friend has a worksheet where some rows are missing data (approximately 20 arrays).  She wants to do the CORREL function on these data sets but omitting the missing data sets.

For example,

[image]

Is it possible to concatenate the arrays on the spreadsheet for use in a function?

Answer (score 1):

If Array (CSE) argument encounters blank cells, formula ignores them, but considers cells with zeros.

Blanks cells produces different results then, if zeros are in there.

You keep blanks or if you intend to have more accurate result, then replaces blanks with zeroes.

**Situation 1:**

[image]

- Formula in Cell `A142`:

`=CORREL(A131:A139,B131:B139)`

- An array (CSE) formula in Cell `A144`:

  `{=CORREL(IF(A131:A139+B131:B139=0,"",A131:A139),IF(A131:A139+B131:B139=0,"",B131:B139))}`
- Array (CSE) formula in Cell `A146` tests blanks has different result, since consider blanks as zero:

  `{=CORREL((IF(ISERROR(A131:A139),"",A131:A139)),(IF(ISERROR(B131:B139),"",B131:B139)))}`

*Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.*

---

**Situation 2:**

*Blank cell replaced with Zeros.*

[image]

**N.B.**

- Now you can find formula in Cell `A142` & in Cell `A146` has similar outcome.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*